# Can i substract 2 column given some conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this
[image: a]

I want to subtract  `EndTime - StartTime` only if `channel` is 1000
smth like this: `df.loc[df['Channel'] == 1000]['X channel view time']=df['EndTime']-df['StartTime']`
this should be the fastest but does not appear to be working so

```
def watch_time(row,channel):
    val=0
    if row['Channel']==channel:
        val=row['EndTime']-row['StartTime']   

    return val
df['BTV_view_time'] = df.apply(watch_time,args=250,axis=1)
```

but this is a lot slower?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for all rows then replace ones that don't fit your filter with `0`:

```
 df['X channel view time'] = df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime']
 df.loc[df['Channel'] == 1000, 'X channel view time'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not that far. Syntax is:

```
df.loc[df['Channel'] == 1000, 'X channel view time']=df.loc[df['Channel'] == 1000, 'EndTime']-df.loc[df['Channel'] == 1000, 'StartTime']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np 
df['X channel view time'] = np.where(df['channel'] == 1000, df['EndTime'] - df['StartTime'], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

notice you are taking a slice of the df, that's why it is not working, you can do something like this:

`smaller_df =  df[df['Channel'] == 1000]['EndTime']-df[df['Channel'] == 1000]['StartTime']`

you can also create a new column:

```
df['subtraction'] = [0]*len(df)
df['subtraction'] = df[df['Channel'] == 1000]['EndTime']-df[df['Channel'] == 1000]['StartTime']
```

replace `[0]*len(df)` by what you want if 'Channel' is different of 1000